# Validating application after Oracle Database upgrade

Tags: oracle, upgrade

We have a large scale enterprise application with Oracle 11g as the backend. Application features Will be tested by using automated testcases and Manual testing. We are planning to upgrade the database to 12c.Once upgraded, are there any services/Tools available for validating/certifying the upgraded Database??

Does upgrading of database consists of validating the Upgrading database or do we need carry out extra steps apart from running all the testcases and comparing the results.

Answer (score 1):

How do you validate / certify your application today, on 11.2 ? If you have no certification test suite, then that is the problem, and you should develop one before migrating.

I recommend:

1. Automated Tests - The database is a sub-system of your application. The best you can do is to produce an exhaustive set of functional tests for your application, to be run before and after the upgrade. Oracle has their own certification procedures that are more than anything you could ever implement, but that doesn't mean their definition of functional is the same as your app's.
2. Test environment - Test the upgrade once before you do it live, with a copy of your live data.
3. A rollback plan. If you find 2 weeks later that 12c has a critical bug, or that you did the upgrade wrong, what will you do? Make sure you have a rollback plan in place.
4. If you have budget, bring up a parallel system, put it online and test it side by side for some "soak time". Run the automated test cases on it prior to the real thing.

Comment: Thanks for the Quick Answer. Can you please point me towards the certification procedures available with the Oracle?

Comment: Oracle has internal certification procedures for certifying its server software on specific platforms. They also have standard test suites for ANSI compliance, among other things. I don't have those, but this is the wrong path, you need to developer your own application specific test cases.

Comment: You can also capture or extract the SQL from your app, and verify that all data is queryable after the upgrade. Still, this is just a type of test case.

Comment: Consider this: How do you validate / certify your application today, on 11.2 ? If you have no certification test suite, then that is the problem, and you should develop one before migrating.

Comment: Have a look at http://learncodewrite.blogspot.com/2017/04/migrating-to-oracle-11g-from-oracle-10g.html post. You will have to look for "order by" issues carefully.